# Bathroom sink won't drain

Tags: drain, sink

I will be forever grateful if someone can help me out!

I installed a new bathroom faucet. Before I did this the sink never had an issue with draining. But I installed the new faucet and now my sink won't drain? I've attached a couple pics. The pipe going into the wall will not take in water? Does anyone know what I've done wrong or how to fix this?

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make sense, but I guess it doesn't have to make sense to be a problem.  If you're sure that you didn't drop anything down the drain, I'd try a plunger.  The way to use it is not to ram it down hard, trying to power any obstruction through.  Rather make many small strokes up and down to break the obstruction up with oscillations.  If you think you did drop something in the drain take the trap apart and get it out.

Comment: Plunging a bathroom sink usually does not work because there is an air vent.  Better to detach the plastic tubing and snake the pipe in the wall.  While you have the plastic detached, see if contains any foreign material.

Comment: Good one.  It would be worth trying to cover the vent and plunge first though. Simply because it is so easy.